# Laravel Blade doesn't include partial

Tags: php, html, laravel, include, laravel-blade

I'm trying to add to my layout a header file like so:

**Views/layouts/main_layout.blade.php**

`@include('layouts.header.stylesheets')`

the content for that file is:

```
@section('stylesheets')
    {{ stylesheet_link_tag('style.css') }}
@stop
```

but that doesn't include anything, could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are including a file, you just do this:

Views/layouts/main_layout.blade.php

```
@include('layouts.header.stylesheets')
```

Then in your other file:

```
{{ stylesheet_link_tag('style.css') }}
```

You only use `@section` if you are `@yielding` to that file